# Compare 2 currencies considering the costs of living and purchasing power index

Tags: linear-algebra

I want calculate how many units of one currency (USD) have the same purchasing power as another currency (Turkish Lira). For this reason I looked up [this](https://www.worlddata.info/cost-of-living.php) site that shows the cost of living index, average salary and purchasing power index of every country.

For example: How many Turkish Lira have the same purchasing power as $1000$ USD, considering the costs of living and purchasing power index (and the exchange rate maybe too?)?

US:

Costs of living index: $100$ (set as the standard)

Purchasing power index: $100$ (set as the standard)

Turkey:

Costs of living index: $42$

Purchasing power index: $34.8$

[Exchange rate: $1$USD = $7.33$TL]

How can I use these indices to see how many TL have the same purchasing power in Turkey as e.g. $1000$ USD in the US? The exchange rate alone won't suffice since the costs of living are much lower in Turkey but the Turkish Lira also has a lower purchasing power index.

I'm very interested in your answers since I'm completely lost.

**EDIT**: It seems that the purchasing power index does not consider housing expenses.

Comment: Is this a mathematics question?

Comment: Yes, since I would need a formula.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As I understand it, $$PPI = \frac{34.8}{100}$$ So, 1000USD in America has the same purchasing power as 348USD in Turkey. Then 1USD = 7.33TL, so 1000USD in America has the same purchasing power as 2550.84TL in Turkey.

So, generalizing, let's call the currency of Country A, AC, and the currency of Country B, BC. $$1000AC\:in\:Country\:A = (1000 * \frac{PPI\:of\:Country\:B}{PPI\:of\:Country\:A}*Conversion\:Rate)\:BC\:in\:Country\:B$$I can't really understand what you're asking for, so I hope this is it...